# comparing field values in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, expression, ireport

I'd like to ask about comparing between field values in *iReport*, here is the code: *`$V{variable2}=($F{value1}==$F{value2})? "100":"0"`*.

I don't know what happened but that code doesn't work as it's expected.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: $F{value1}.equals($F{value2})

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to make an assignment of a variable inside another variable or do you just want to assign the variable? If it indeed is the former I suggest you add another set of parentheses around the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If $V{variable2} expression is

```
 ($F{value1}==$F{value2})? "100":"0"
```

And that doesnt work you may need to try to compare the primitive values or the object oriented equals() method that Alex K mentioned.  Assuming the fields are integers.

```
($F{value1}.intValue() == $F{value2}.intValue() )? "100":"0"
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need  "", so the above should work fine:

```
($F{value1}==$F{value2}) ?  100 : 0
```